# I have an onChange function with this parameters that works fine but I also want to apply the function onLoad

Tags: javascript, html

I have an onchange function that when pending is selected, it will add a value in the input field, but I also want this to apply onload, currently, pending is already selected, so when the page loads, i want to add a value to the input field.

```js
function validateForm1(k, x) {
  if (x.value == "pending") {
    document.getElementById(k).value = "populate";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="target1">

<select data-uid="target1" onchange="validateForm1(this.getAttribute('data-uid'),this)">
  <option></option>
  <option selected value="pending">pending</option>
  <option value="testing">testing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you know the value you want to set, create a variable for it. and call `validateForm1(variable1,variable2) ` on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your validate function and to populate the variables you can find them with javascript functions like `getElementsByName`. That's the easiest way with the code you have, but, to improve on it, I would suggest adding an id to your `select` and then using `getElementById` to get the element.

Here's a working solution:

```js
function validateForm1(k, x) {
  if (x.value == "pending") {
    document.getElementById(k).value = "populate";
  }
}
validateForm1(document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].getAttribute('data-uid'), document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="target1">

<select data-uid="target1" onchange="validateForm1(this.getAttribute('data-uid'),this)">
  <option></option>
  <option selected value="pending">pending</option>
  <option value="testing">testing</option>
</select>
```